# Sort JSON array by timestamp, extract key/value pairs and write to google sheet

Tags: arrays, json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to take info from a JSON array in a Google Sheet and take the last chronological entry in the array and copy it into the two adjacent columns

The data I want is in Column L of my sheet (starting in row 2) and in the format:

```
[{"id": "XX:123456", "timestamp": "2020-01-27T19:25:51.303"}, {"id": "XX:654321", "timestamp": "2020-01-27T19:40:37.06"}]
```

```
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("data");
var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
var lastRow = dataRange.getLastRow();

function parseData() {

   let parseRange = sheet.getRange(1+1,11,lastRow-1,1); //col L
   let values = parseRange.getValues();
   let out = values.map(([row])=>{
      let {id, timestamp} = JSON.parse(row).pop();
      return [id, timestamp];
   });
   sheet.getRange(1+1, 12, lastRow-1, 2).setValues(out);
}
```

This is extracting data from the array, however since the JSON itself is not sorted, I need to ensure it is taking the id, and timestamp for the object with the latest timestamp chronologically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to find the latest:

```
let {id, timestamp} = JSON.parse(row).reduce(
    (a,c) => a.timestamp > c.timestamp ? a : c //lexigographic enough for iso8601
)
```